# Elements within a container that have the relative positon won't align horizontally with display: inline

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make these elements align in rows up to the end of the container and not overflow off it. But they won't align at all even when I apply display:inline to each of the individual elements. float:left; seems to leave a large gap in the top row, I'm not sure what is causing this all to happen.

```css
.itemShopDaily {
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.2em;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6,0.1fr);
}
.itemShopWeekly {

}
.itemContainer {
    width: 116px;
    height: 116px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    border-image-slice: 20;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.itemDetails {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
}
.itemName {
    background: rgba(0,7,36,0.5);
    padding: 3px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.itemPrice {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #000724;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2px 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: white;
}
.itemPrice img {
    width: 1.5em;
    padding-right: 0.3rem;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='itemShopDaily'>
        <div class="itemContainer testItem">
          <img src="URL" class="itemImage">
          <div class="itemDetails">
              <div class="itemName">SAMPLE</div>
              <div class="itemPrice">
                  <img src="URL" />
                  <span>Sample</span>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="itemContainer testItem">
          <img src="URL" class="itemImage">
          <div class="itemDetails">
              <div class="itemName">SAMPLE</div>
              <div class="itemPrice">
                  <img src="URL" />
                  <span>Sample</span>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="itemContainer testItem">
          <img src="URL" class="itemImage">
            <div class="itemDetails">
              <div class="itemName">SAMPLE</div>
              <div class="itemPrice">
                  <img src="URL" />
                  <span>Sample</span>
             </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

What is causing this to happen, why won't they align horizontally, why does display-inline not work?
A working example is also available here: http://fortniteprosnipes.x10.bz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format your Code properly and it works, because you'll see you have forgotten many closing `</div>` tags!

```css
.itemShopDaily {
    margin-bottom: 0.2em;
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 0.2em;
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6,0.1fr);
}
.itemShopWeekly {

}
.itemContainer {
    width: 116px;
    height: 116px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    border-image-slice: 20;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.itemDetails {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
}
.itemName {
    background: rgba(0,7,36,0.5);
    padding: 3px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.itemPrice {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #000724;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2px 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: white;
}
.itemPrice img {
    width: 1.5em;
    padding-right: 0.3rem;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='itemShopDaily'>
    <div class="itemContainer testItem">
        <div class="itemDetails">
            <div class="itemName">SAMPLE</div>
            <div class="itemPrice">
                <span>Sample</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="itemContainer testItem">
            <div class="itemDetails">
                <div class="itemName">SAMPLE</div>
                <div class="itemPrice">
                    <span>Sample</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="itemContainer testItem">
            <div class="itemDetails">
                <div class="itemName">SAMPLE
                </div>
                <div class="itemPrice">
                    <span>Sample</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's a much simpler version:

```css
.itemShopDaily {
    margin-bottom: 0.2em;
}
.itemContainer {
    width: 116px;
    height: 116px;
    position: relative;
    border: 4px solid;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
}
.itemDetails {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
}
.itemName {
    background: rgba(0,7,36,0.5);
    padding: 3px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.itemPrice {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #000724;
    padding: 2px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
.itemPrice img {
    width: 1.5em;
    padding-right: 0.3rem;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='itemShopDaily'>
    <div class="itemContainer testItem">
        <div class="itemDetails">
            <div class="itemName">SAMPLE</div>
            <div class="itemPrice">
                <span>Sample</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="itemContainer testItem">
            <div class="itemDetails">
                <div class="itemName">SAMPLE</div>
                <div class="itemPrice">
                    <span>Sample</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="itemContainer testItem">
            <div class="itemDetails">
                <div class="itemName">SAMPLE
                </div>
                <div class="itemPrice">
                    <span>Sample</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there an alternative way to do this without using display: grid like I have in the example?

Comment: I've edited my post. You can use `float: left` for aligning the items in a horizontal order.

Comment: float: left causes elements to shift out of place

Comment: You should delete the `<br>`s.

Comment: Thanks for the help, is there anyway I am able to contact you if I require any other assistance?

Comment: Remember to mark my answer as solution. You can always ask a new question on stackoverflow - the community is huge and always helpful :)